# Product of closures is closure of products -- simpler proof

Tags: general-topology

From Munkres, I'm interested in part of the proof of the aforementioned fact, specifically if we have indexed topological spaces $X_\alpha$ and arbitrary sets $A_\alpha \subset X_\alpha$ then $\prod{\bar{A_\alpha}} = \overline{\prod{A_\alpha}}$ in **both box and product topologies**, specifically $\supseteq$ part.

Can't we just say that left side is a closed set which obviously contains $\prod{A_\alpha}$ and right side is the smallest closed set containing it and that's it. Why did Munkres complicate it?

Comment: What do you mean by "complicate it"? What exactly does he write? Note that with your approach you still need to prove that the left side is closed.

Comment: Product of closed sets is closed, isn't that a known fact? We can just use intersection of preimages of projections. Well, he uses points inside these sets which may be confusing for a first read.

Comment: I've looked at the book. I don't see him proving that projections are continuous in both topologies. At least not before theorem 19.5. But even if he does, the way he proves it is not complicated. Well at least in my opinion. It is just a different way. Btw, your approach is correct assuming we know that the product of closed sets is closed.